# MTFT: Invalid configuration value provided for "region"

Tags: magento2.4, aws, mftf

I am trying to run the functional tests but it is returning an error:

```
$ /vendor/bin/codecept run functional -c dev/tests/acceptance/codeception.yml


Invalid configuration value provided for "region". Expected string, but got bool(false)  
                                                                                           
  region: (string)
```

I got some tips here on the MTFT github repository:

https://github.com/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/issues/821

But I have not been capable to fix it yet.

It is clearly related to AWS S3 bucket, but I have not configured it on my local.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by having AWS3 module enabled without the correct credentials.

It is missing these values from your dev/tests/acceptance/.env

REMOTE_STORAGE_AWSS3_REGION=us-west-2
REMOTE_STORAGE_AWSS3_BUCKET=my-test-bucket
REMOTE_STORAGE_AWSS3_PREFIX=local

If you don't want to use AWS3, just disable it.
`bin/magento module:disable Magento_AwsS3`

Then regenerate your tests
`vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests -r`

Finally tests works
`vendor/bin/codecept run functional -c dev/tests/acceptance/codeception.yml`

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall aws using composer (composer require aws/aws-sdk-php). If you don't use it, you can remove it from your project.

Answer (score 0):

There is an update on the github issue to use the "-r" flag after adding a .credentials file, which worked for me. I was used it as
`vendor/bin/mftf run:group -r <group>` so I'm not sure what that means for direct codecept usage.

Likely you can remove the generated tests directory and re-try your command, or try `codecept clean` after creating the .credentials file.